# Switching colors of div tables using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a small project where I have 3x3 columns of div tables.

if i click on one column it should change background color, if i click on another column it should change color of selected column but the previous selected column should change back to normal color.

everything works as i want. but only one problem, when i select the column and move to another column the color remains on the previously selected column. Below is my code.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Div Tag Table Layout</title>
        <style>


         .table-row{  
             display:table-row;
             text-align: center;
         }
         .col{ 
            display:table-cell;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            width: 100px;   height: 100px;
            cursor:pointer;


         }


        .yellow-bg { background-color: yellow; }

        .grey-bg { background-color: green; }


        </style>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


         $(function() {
            $('div').hover(function() {
                div = $(this).attr('para'); //grab #one, #two which correspond to the div id we're targetting

                paragraph = $(div); //store each div in a variable for later use        

                  $(paragraph).toggleClass('yellow-bg'); //add grey background to clicked element



            });


             $('div').click(function() {
                div = $(this).attr('para'); //grab #one, #two which correspond to the div id we're targetting

                paragraph = $(div); //store each div in a variable for later use        


                  $(paragraph).toggleClass('grey-bg'); //add grey background to clicked element


            });




        });


        </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="table-row">
                     <div class="col"  id="one" para="#one">.</div>
                      <div class="col" id="two" para="#two">.</div>
                       <div class="col" id="three" para="#three">.</div>

            </div>
            <div class="table-row" > 
                     <div class="col" id="four" para="#four">.</div>
                      <div class="col" id="five" para="#five">.</div>
                       <div class="col" id="six" para="#six">.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                     <div class="col" id="seven" para="#seven">.</div>
                      <div class="col" id="eight" para="#eight">.</div>
                       <div class="col" id="nine" para="#nine">.</div>
            </div


        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have many useless things on your html and javascript.

**For example:**

`para` attribute is not really useful, because you can access the    `hovered` or `clicked` element by simply using `$(this)` on your    event handler.

So, to put the last toggled `.col` into its initial background, you need to get it like this:

```
var lastToggled = $('.table-row > .col.grey-bg');
```

and check if it is different from the clicked div, if it is the remove the its `grey-bg` class:

```
if(lastToggled[0] !== $(this)[0])
    lastToggled.removeClass('grey-bg');
```

and finally, toggle the `grey-bg` class for the clicked div.

```
$(this).toggleClass('grey-bg');
```

So your javascript will look like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.table-row > .col').hover(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('yellow-bg');
   });

   $('.table-row > .col').click(function() {
       var lastToggled = $('.table-row > .col.grey-bg');
       if(lastToggled[0] !== $(this)[0])
           lastToggled.removeClass('grey-bg');

       $(this).toggleClass('grey-bg'); 
   });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jcmzjL5/)

Comment: It worked thanks :)

what does this line do ?

$('.table-row > .col.grey-bg');

Comment: Is to select the divs cols with `grey-bg` class. If that helped you please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler i guess

```
$('.table-row .col').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow-bg'); 
});

$('.table-row .col').click(function() {
      $('.table-row .col.grey-bg').removeClass('grey-bg');                  
      $(this).addClass('grey-bg'); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5cajw6e/

Comment: I tried something similar to this before but it did not work.

 $('div').removeClass('grey-bg'); //add grey background to clicked element

 $(paragraph).toggleClass('grey-bg'); //add grey background to clicked element

but your code worked , really weird.

Comment: may be some issue with your paragraph variable! and y do u use toggleClass in this case. use addClass instead.